# How do I enable adb tracing

Tags: android

I am intrested in viewing the packets sent by between adb client and adbd through usb. I tried setting the environment variable ADB_TRACE to 1. But when I run "adb shell" though the shell comes up, I am not able to see any traces. Any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try `adb logcat`.  That will show you the log.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to type some commands in the terminal:

```
adb kill-server
export ADB_TRACE=all
adb start-server
```

Comment: This is missing those 2 steps:

    `ps aux | grep adb  # Find the process ID`
    `less /proc/<process ID>/fd/1`

Answer (score 1):

Below patch should help you. More info is present at https://events.linuxfoundation.org/images/stories/pdf/lf_abs12_kobayashi.pdf

```
diff --git a/adb/adb.h b/adb/adb.h
index 622ca70..ecf9597 100644
--- a/adb/adb.h
+++ b/adb/adb.h
@@ -379,7 +379,7 @@ void adb_qemu_trace(const char* fmt, ...);
  extern unsigned char    adb_trace_output_count;
  void    adb_trace_init(void);

-#  define ADB_TRACING  ((adb_trace_mask & (1 << TRACE_TAG)) != 0)  
+#  define ADB_TRACING  1//((adb_trace_mask & (1 << TRACE_TAG)) != 0)

   /* you must define TRACE_TAG before using this macro */
#  define  D(...)                                      \
@@ -415,7 +415,7 @@ void adb_qemu_trace(const char* fmt, ...);
#endif


-#if !DEBUG_PACKETS
+#if 1//!DEBUG_PACKETS
 #define print_packet(tag,p) do {} while (0)
#endif
```